# MATLAB imfindcircles() not working properly even with my very basic test image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I need to finde some somewhat vague circle-like structures in a lot of microscope pictures, and hope that imfindcircles can help me do that. So just to get started, I have created a rather random, basic test picture. Shown in the code are two examples found on the net. The one with the coins looks like a challenging task, but the function easily identifies the circles.

In my image, I can find one at best. What is the problem? Am I making some obvious mistake?

```
 % Example from web
im = imread('http://kimyamuhendisi.com/images/pipe.jpg');
[c,r] = imfindcircles(im,[10,20]);
figure, imshow(im); viscircles(c,r);

% Example from web
A = imread('coins.png');
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(A,[15 30]);
figure, imshow(A); viscircles(centers, radii, 'EdgeColor', 'b');

% My test picture
Iuint8 = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbUJv.jpg');
Igray = rgb2gray(Iuint8); 
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[10 30]); %Finds B
% [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[20 40]) %Nothing
% [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[30 50]) %Nothing
% [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[50 70]) %Nothing
% [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[70 90]) %Nothing
% [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[90 120]) %Nothing
% [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Igray,[240 270]) %Nothing
figure, imshow(Igray); viscircles(centers, radii, 'EdgeColor', 'b');
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html). There are options to increase the sensitivity (which you need here). But most importantly, you’ll discover that the name of the function is misleading, as it detects disks rather than circles (solid circular objects, not hollow ones like a, b and c in your example image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks but you shouldn't assume that I didn't bother reading the documentation before posting my question. Could you show me some commands that would find some of my circles? The gray ones indeed are solid disks. And again, the coins didn't need any adjustment of sensitivity.

Comment: The coins image is simple: there are only coins. The gradient will be strongest at the coin edges. In your case, the gray disks have very low contrast compared to other things, the gradient will be much stronger elsewhere. This will cause the automated threshold to ignore the gradient around your gray disks. Therefore you need to increase the sensitivity of the threshold. The hollow circles, which have a high contrast, will likely not be found correctly by this function, but would be by a regular Hough Transform.